# Detect closing of delete button (Swipe to delete) on UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to detect closing of delete button on UITableView. So, I write inside this.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{

}
```

When I output otherGestureRecognizer, I saw like this.

```
(lldb) po otherGestureRecognizer
<UIGobblerGestureRecognizer: 0x7fbd8c21ccb0; state = Ended; view = <UITableView 0x7fbd89953000>; target= <(action=_handleSwipeDeleteGobbler:, target=<UITableView 0x7fbd89953000>)>>
```

I need to check like this. But, it is not allowed and need to use UISwipeGestureRecognizer. May I know how to detect whether user is closing Delete button in UITableViewCell?

```
if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIGobblerGestureRecognizer class]])
{    
}
```

Comment: which delete button? swipe to delete button?

Comment: Yes. Swipe to delete button

Comment: what you exactly want to know? do you mean if I swipe and swipe again and doesn't use Delete option?

Comment: I am trying to capture whether user swipe to the Right direction to hide Delete button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `UITableView` delegate, you can use `tableView:didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:` to get notified when the editing of the cell ends, which is also the state when the `Delete` button is about to disappear.

Comment: lol..I am making long code. Thanks. It is useful. I notice that it is also being called when Delete button appear. Is it true?

Comment: I don't think so. It should only be called when editing ends. However, you can use `tableView:willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:` or  `tableView:didBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:` for that.